Forgetting a wifi password
I have created a cheap flask app to sell my WiFi. The device connects through the app on an intranet then it connects using pywifi then I use a schedule function to manage the time. Now I need a way to make the device forget the password once its disconnected when their airtime has ran out.
def connect_to_wifi(ssid, password):
    wifi = PyWiFi()
    iface = wifi.interfaces()[0]
    profile = Profile()
    profile.ssid = ssid
    profile.auth = const.AUTH_ALG_OPEN
    profile.akm.append(const.AKM_TYPE_WPA2PSK)
    profile.cipher = const.CIPHER_TYPE_CCMP
    profile.key = password
    iface.remove_all_network_profiles()
    iface.add_network_profile(profile)
    iface.connect(iface.add_network_profile(profile))  # Attempt to connect
    # Check connection status
    if iface.status() == const.IFACE_CONNECTED:
        print(f"Successfully connected to {ssid}")
    else:
        print("Failed to connect")

connect_to_wifi('Nimrodian', '12345678nm')
def disconnect_wifi():
    iface.disconnect()
    #forget paswword mechanism
    return schedule.CancelJob

schedule.every(30).minutes.do(disconnect_wifi)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)


The device may forget your password but it's immortalized right here in your question on SO.

A Good approach would be to instantiate every connections, assuming you might have more than one person using your service.
Creating a WiFiConnection class
class WiFiConnection:
    def __init__(self, ssid, password):
        self.ssid = ssid
        self.password = password
        self.wifi = PyWiFi()
        self.iface = self.wifi.interfaces()[0]
        self.profile = None

    def connect(self):
        # Set up the WiFi profile
        self.profile = Profile()
        self.profile.ssid = self.ssid
        self.profile.auth = const.AUTH_ALG_OPEN
        self.profile.akm.append(const.AKM_TYPE_WPA2PSK)
        self.profile.cipher = const.CIPHER_TYPE_CCMP
        self.profile.key = self.password
        
        self.profile = self.iface.add_network_profile(self.profile)
        
        # Connect to the WiFi network
        self.iface.connect(self.profile)
        time.sleep(5)
        
        if self.iface.status() == const.IFACE_CONNECTED:
            print(f"Successfully connected to {self.ssid}")
        else:
            print(f"Failed to connect to {self.ssid}")

    def disconnect(self):
        self.iface.disconnect()
        time.sleep(2)
        print(f"Disconnected from {self.ssid}")

    def forget(self):
        self.iface.remove_all_network_profiles()
        print(f"Forgot the WiFi credentials for {self.ssid}")

You can use this class to create a new connection.
new_connection = WiFiConnection("your_ssid", "your_wifi_password")

Use the WiFiConnection instance new_connection to manage the connection with the connect() disconnect() and forget() methods
You need to update your schedule function to disconnect a specific connection and not disconnect everyone.
def schedule_disconnection(connection, delay_minutes):
    def terminate_connection():
        connection.disconnect()
        connection.forget()
        return schedule.CancelJob

    # Schedule the termination after a given time
    schedule.every(delay_minutes).minutes.do(terminate_connection)

Here is a full usage example:
active_connections = [] # Optional

new_connection = WiFiConnection("your_ssid", "your_wifi_password")
new_connection.connect()

active_connetions.append(new_connection)


# 30 minutes schedule
schedule_disconnection(new_connection, 30)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)

You could implement this in your Flask app by having the app create a new connection every time a user uses the service.
